# Webview not loading when inflated

Tags: android, webview, android-inflate

I am working on an app with a navigation drawer that can show several screens. These pages are all shown within the same `Activity` though by inflating them into a wrapper.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    //some parameters 

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One of these screens contains a `WebView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To the Webview I attach a `WebViewClient` to handle some html manipulation with Javascript.

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
if (webView == null) {
    inflateLayout(R.layout.layout_with_webview);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
}
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://www.somesite.com");
```

If I put the `WebView` into the layout that is loaded with `setContentView()` when the activity starts everything loads correctly. After that I inflate a different Layout into the `main_container` using the following code:

```
public void inflateLayout(int toinflate) {
    ConstraintLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(toinflate, null);
    mainLayout.removeAllViews();
    mainLayout.addView(layout);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

When I now want to inflate a Layout containing a `WebView` nothing is shown when I call `webView.loadUrl("some url")` eventhough the `onPageFinished(...)`method is being called.

Now the question is: what am I doing wrong and how can I use WebViews that are attached to the Screen using inflation.

Also: I already tried adding the WebView using `addView` and it did not work.

Comment: You are not providing the constraints in webview tag. Try adding the constraints and then check

Comment: Adding the constraints did not change anything. Also If I put the WebView in the default layout it renders without any problems

Comment: @MushahidGillani it's a good idea, but I guess, it should work without it as we'll due to being an only child having match parent but read my answer as well

Comment: r u sure that your `webView` is null here `(webView == null)` ?check it

Comment: It is null everytime the webview is not currently displayed (that means when i am showing a different layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the new inflated layout references

```
public void inflateLayout(int toinflate) {
    ConstraintLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(toinflate, null);
    mainLayout.removeAllViews();
    mainLayout.addView(layout);

   // you need to reinitialise the web view which will refer to 
   // the web view in newly inflated layout as
   webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

because the new related view has no link with the existing layout of the activity hence the web view is loading normally but will have no effect on screen

Inflation is expensive so the efficient option is [Fragments](http://fragment%20android)

---

**Update :** : The inflated layout must have appropriate layout param according to the constraint layout so use

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(toinflate, mainLayout);
```

Comment: My provided method works with all layouts except with the one containing the webview though. Adding the setContentView() did not work and it just kept showing a blank screen. I considered using Fragments, I wanted to try solving it this way first though.

Comment: I already call those lines after I called inflateLayout(). I forgot to add the corresponding lines in the question and changed them now (cut a few too many lines when copying)

Comment: no it is still wrong, Kindly pay attention to updated code

Comment: My code reflects your code's functionality. I cannot add the webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view); into the inflateLayout() method as I also inflate other layout in there. That is why I am setting the WebViewClient after the inflateLayout method is finished. The webview is null everytime i expect it to be null.

Comment: can you simply try this `WebView webView  = null;
inflateLayout(R.layout.layout_with_webview);
webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/webview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The parent layout is ConstraintLayout while the child component i.e webView is not really having valid properties. Check this layout in preview first are you able to see your webview in it?
if not try these-

```
<WebView
      android:id="@+id/web_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Adding those constraints did not help sorry.